# Get unknown account when sending transaction to ethereum testnet network

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I am using `web3` library to send transaction to Ethereum testnet network.

Below is the code:

```
const w = new web3(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ETHEREUM_NETWORK);
const transaction: Transaction = {
        from: account.address,
        to:address,
        gas: Number(gas),
        gasPrice: BigInt(gasPrice),
        gasLimit: Number(gas) * 2,
        nonce: Number(await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address)),
        value: BigInt(cellPriceValue),
        data: ...
      };
await w.eth.signTransaction(transaction);
```

I got below error when run this code:

```
error: 101 InvalidResponseError: Returned error: unknown account
```

how can I set the account when sending the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error `unknown account` is indicating that the account you're trying to send the transaction from is not recognised or accessible by the node you're connected to.

To set the account when sending the transaction using the **web3.js** library, you need to provide the private key of the account from which you're sending the transaction. Here's how you can modify your code to include the private key:

```js
const w = new web3(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ETHEREUM_NETWORK);

// Assuming you have the private key stored in a variable
const privateKey = '0xYOUR_PRIVATE_KEY'; // Please never use your private key in plain text ever.

// Convert the private key to an Ethereum account
const account = w.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);   // Ensure that private key is having '0x' prefix

const transaction: Transaction = {
  from: account.address,
  to: address,
  gas: Number(gas),
  gasPrice: BigInt(gasPrice),
  gasLimit: Number(gas) * 2,
  nonce: Number(await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address)),
  value: BigInt(cellPriceValue),
  data: ...
};

// Sign the transaction with the account's private key
const signedTransaction = await account.signTransaction(transaction);

// Send the signed transaction
const transactionReceipt = await w.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);

console.log('Transaction hash:', transactionReceipt.transactionHash);
```

Also, to pass the exact `gas` and `gasPrice`, you can also calculate the same using these methods before signing and sending the transaction:

```js
// Get current gas price
w.eth.getGasPrice()
    .then(async (gasPrice) => {

        // Estimate gas limit
        w.eth.estimateGas({
            from: account.address,
            to: address,
            nonce: Number(await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address)),
            value: BigInt(cellPriceValue),
            data: ""
        }).then(async (gasLimit) => {
            const transaction = {
                from: account.address,
                to: address,
                gas: gasLimit,
                gasPrice: gasPrice,
                nonce: Number(await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address)),
                value: BigInt(cellPriceValue),
                data: ""
            };

            // Sign the transaction with the account's private key
            const signedTransaction = await account.signTransaction(transaction);

            // Send the signed transaction
            const transactionReceipt = await w.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);

            console.log('Transaction hash:', transactionReceipt.transactionHash);

        });
});
```

**P.S., FOR SECURITY PURPOSES, NEVER USE YOUR PRIVATE KEY AS PLAIN TEXT EVER.**

---

**FOR BROWSER ENVIRONMENT:**

For doing a transaction by connecting to MetaMask and performing & confirming the transaction, it has to be done in a browser environment using the injected provider of MetaMask through the `window.ethereum` object of the browser.

Here's the minimal HTML code for the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MetaMask Interaction</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>MetaMask Interaction</h1>

    <button id="connectButton">Connect to MetaMask</button>
    <button id="transactionButton" disabled>Perform Transaction</button>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.5.3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Function to handle MetaMask connection
        async function connectMetaMask() {
            try {
                // Check if MetaMask is installed
                if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined' && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
                    // Request access to user accounts
                    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

                    // Enable the transaction button
                    document.getElementById('transactionButton').disabled = false;

                    console.log('Connected to MetaMask. Selected account:', accounts[0]);
                } else {
                    console.error('MetaMask is not installed or unlocked.');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        }
        // Function to perform transaction
        async function performTransaction() {
            try {
                // Create a web3 instance using MetaMask's provider
                const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

                // Get the current selected account's address
                const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
                const fromAddress = accounts[0];

                // Example: Prepare a transaction
                const transaction = {
                    from: fromAddress,
                    to: 'RECIPIENT_ADDRESS', // Replace with recipient address
                    value: web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether') // Example: Send 0.01 ether (ETH/MATIC depending on the network you're connected to)
                    // Add other transaction parameters as needed
                };

                // Send the transaction using MetaMask
                const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction);

                console.log('Transaction hash:', transactionReceipt.transactionHash);

                alert(`Transaction hash: ${transactionReceipt.transactionHash}`);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        }

        // Connect to MetaMask when the connect button is clicked
        document.getElementById('connectButton').addEventListener('click', connectMetaMask);

        // Perform transaction when the transaction button is clicked
        document.getElementById('transactionButton').addEventListener('click', performTransaction);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know providing private key works but is it the right way to do so? When building a dapp, we can't get the private key from customers. I expect the transaction should open metamask from browsers' extension to ask users' approval which will provide the private key?

Comment: For a dApp, it has to be done in a browser environment like HTML (that can be further utilised in full-fledged React or any other frontend framework based apps) using the `window.ethereum` object of the browser that acts as an injected provider. I've edited my answer to add the minimal HTML code to achieve the same.